# Using variables in multiple functions - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm looking to fetch some data then use it to fetch some other data, the first api returns a some news articles, I'm doing a for loop to access descriptions and save it as an `array`, I want then to use that array to make another fetch request, the issue is that I'm only able to access `array`in the first function, my code looks like that:

```
makeRemoteRequest = () => {
  const url = `https://url.com`;
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {

      maindata = res.articles
      var array = []
      for(let i in maindata){
        array.push(maindata[i].description)
      }

      console.log(array) // Working

      this.setState({
        data: res.articles,
      });
    })

    console.log(array) // Not working
    console.log(this.state.data) // Not working
};
```

I'm able to use `this.state.data` in component and render it on a listview.

Second function:

```
  fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
       'api_key': "81a354b",
       'data': array
    }),
  })
```

My last attempt was to mix everything in a single function since it's all promises, didn't work

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => return res.articles.map(article => article.description) )
  .then(res => fetch(otherUrl, { descriptions: res }))
  .then(res => {

  })
```

Comment: the `return` in the second `then` chain is redundant, since it's implied without braces

Comment: I think fetch is an asynchronous function. That's why you are getting an empty result even though the variable already declared outside the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the variable outside of the fetch scope first.
`let array = [];`

Then inside the fetch:

`array.push()`

Comment: same behavior, I'm getting an empty array

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of this? (could you please add the output formatted in your question?):

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => return res.articles.map(article => article.description) )
  .then(res => fetch(otherUrl, { descriptions: res }))
  //I assume that result needs to be parsed as json as well
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => {
    conole.log("got results:",results);
  })
  .catch(err =>
    console.warn("something went wrong:",err);
  )
```